# Confusion on the signs in the complex scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, conventions, fourier-transform, notation

I saw there are different ways we can write down the complex scalar field. For example, in most textbooks I can find, this is defined as
$$\phi(x) =\int \dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\left(a_p e^{-ipx}+b^\dagger_{p}e^{ipx}\right).$$
On my lecture note, it is $$\phi(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}
\left[b_{-p}^\dagger+a_p\right]e^{ipx}.$$
I know they should represent the same thing, but I still have trouble understanding how to transform the first one into the second. If we rewrite the second as
$$\phi(x) = \int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}
\left[b_{-p}^\dagger+a_p\right]e^{ipx}=\int \dfrac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2E_p}}\left(a_p e^{ipx}+b^\dagger_{p}e^{-ipx}\right),$$
there is still a difference in the sign on the exponential. I noticed this is consistent with [Tong's lecture note](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/two.pdf) p.33 (equation 2.69) I think all resources have the same $(-,+,+,+)$ signature. So how can I transform one into the other?

Comment: Which lecture notes? Which page? Link?

Comment: Are you sure your $ipx$ is not rather a three-dimensional vector dot product $i\vec p \cdot \vec x$?

Comment: @hft And yes it is dot product

Comment: Link? Which eq?

Answer (score 2):

I think your lecture notes have the wrong sign.  Annihilators should always be multipled by the wavefunction of the state they annihilate. So if $a^\dagger_{\bf k}$ creates, and $a_{\bf k}$ annihilates, a state of momentum ${\bf k}$ the field expansion should have
$$
a_{\bf k} e^{i({\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}- Et)}+\ldots\\
=a_{\bf k}e^{-ik x} \quad \hbox {in (+,-,-,-)}\\
=a_{\bf k}e^{+ik x} \quad \hbox {in (-,+,+,+)}
$$

This ensures that
$$
\langle 0| \phi({\bf x},0) |{\bf k}\rangle  \propto  e^{i {\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}}
$$

Note added: In Tong's notes the exponentials are purely *spatial* momenta, not 4-momenta. Also he is using the (+---) metric convention. I assume that the notation in your your equation is 4-dimensional  $x=(t,{\bf x})$?